# pageX and pageY not working but offset does

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems with `pageX` and `pageY` from JQuery

I do call a method named `clickOnImage` from my html, like this:

```
<img id="irrelevant" src="beispielbild1.png" onClick="clickOnImage(this);"/>
```

and then JQuery alerts me (as wanted) the 2 offset Values but not the pageX and pageY values.
It is saying undefined

```
function clickOnImage(img) {
    var offsetTop = $(img).offset().top;
    var offsetLeft = $(img).offset().left;
    var positionTop = $(img).pageX;
    var positionLeft = $(img).pageY;
    alert(offsetTop);
    alert(offsetLeft);
    alert(positionTop);
    alert(positionLeft);
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I don't think pageX/pageY applies to elements, only events, see http://api.jquery.com/event.pagex/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pageX and pageY are not methods in jQuery, they are properties of an event object. You could do:

```
$(function() {
    $("#irrelevant").on("click", function(e) {
      var offsetTop = $(this).offset().top;
      var offsetLeft = $(this).offset().left;
      var positionTop = e.pageX;
      var positionLeft = e.pageY;
      alert(offsetTop);
      alert(offsetLeft);
      alert(positionTop);
      alert(positionLeft);
    });
})
```

Comment: no I cant do this, since I have a lot of Images, with different ID´s :/

Comment: the onliest, thing that im allowed to modify in the html is this part: onClick="clickOnImage(this);"/>

Comment: If you can't change the script, then you are out of luck, since the img-parameter can't contain both offset and pageX properties...

Comment: the script i can change, but not the html

Comment: So use my script then? Whats the problem? Change the selector part to select the images you need.

Comment: the problem is, that the id and the class are dynamically generated and change every time(something like dfrefxdvreavdreafg43vd4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60688/discussion-between-esa-and-felix-lahmer).